# Do you need to advertise an AFP service via Avahi for an Ubuntu Server to show up in OSX Finder?

Tags: ubuntu, mac-osx, nfs, avahi

I am only advertising an NFS share plus the "model", and I don't want to install extra services on the Server unless I have to, ie netatalk, as it is used solely for NFS exports.

Currently there is no entry in Finder under "Shared" with below config of Avahi.

```
serveradmin@FILESERVER:/etc/avahi/services$ cat nfs.service
<?xml version="1.0" standalone='no'?><!--*-nxml-*-->
<!DOCTYPE service-group SYSTEM "avahi-service.dtd">
<service-group>
<name replace-wildcards="yes">%h</name>
<service>
<type>_nfs._tcp</type>
<port>2049</port>
<txt-record>path=/Volumes/StoragePool</txt-record>
</service>
<service>
<type>_device-info._tcp</type>
<port>0</port>
<txt-record>model=Xserve</txt-record>
</service>
</service-group>
```

Server: Ubuntu 12.04.01 x64
Clients: OSX 10.6.8 , 10.7.5, 10.8.2

The goal is to advertise that NFS share, then assign a really old Model code of Mac like a Powermac and switch out the icon for a more "LinuxServer-y" one. Plus allow users to connect to NFS in a manner they are familiar with like our other Xserve servers.

I think Avahi is working in general as if I do: `nfs://FILESERVER.local/Volumes/StoragePool` it will connect fine.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

According to [this Mac OS X Hints posting](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20071116042238744), browsing for NFS broke/was removed in OS X 10.5, and I can't find any indication that it's ever come back. The post links to a script for automounting Bonjour-discovered NFS shares on OS X, and it looks like there's a newer version on github under the name [bonjour-nfs](https://github.com/billitch/bonjour-nfs).